# Read XML file to HTML

Tags: html, xml

Is there any possibility to show XML file structure within choosen `<div></div>` in HTML ?

I mean, I have a tree structure saved within XML file and I want to show this tree on certain place on my web page.

**XML structure file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE contact [
    <!ELEMENT contact (telefone_number)>
    <!ELEMENT telefone_number (#PCDATA)>
]>
<contact>
    <telefone_number>2203033</telefone_number>
</contact>
```

Comment: You can try to add an `<iframe>` element that points on your xml file. What is the result of this?

Comment: If you want the contact and telephone number to be displayed, take a look at XSLT. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: `<iframe src="./yourfile.xml"></iframe>` It is just a shoot into the dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load and manipulate an XML file using jQuery and it's Ajax functions.
I suggest you to read this article, it's very useful.

https://blog.udemy.com/jquery-xml/

It is also possibile to manage with PHP if you are using that preprocessor.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp

**Example with Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/myfile.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    //what to do if the file is loaded
    success: function(xml) {
        var number = $(xml).find('contact > telefone_number').text();
        //etc.
    }
    //what to do if there are errors
    error: function() {
        alert("Cannot load XML file");
    }
    });

});
```